# Graphics.MeasureString() returns size in Point or Pixel?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, graphics

I use Graphics.MeasureString to calculate size of a text.
**EG: 10 pixel = 7.5 Point.**

My question:
Is the size calculated from Graphics.MeasureString point value or pixel value?

Comment: Why not check MSDN before coming here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method returns a SizeF structure that represents the size, in the
>   units specified by the PageUnit property, of the string specified by
>   the text parameter as drawn with the font parameter.

The `PageUnit` is of type `GraphicsUnit` which is an enum with the following 
[values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Member name**       Description
**Display** Specifies the unit of measure of the display device. Typically **pixels**   for video displays, and 1/100 inch for printers.
**Document** Specifies the document unit (1/300 inch) as the unit of measure.
**Inch**    Specifies the inch as the unit of measure.
**Millimeter**  Specifies the millimeter as the unit of measure.
**Pixel**   Specifies a device pixel as the unit of measure.
**Point**   Specifies a printer's point (1/72 inch) as the unit of measure.
**World**   Specifies the world coordinate system unit as the unit of measure.

Apologies for the terrible formatting!

Comment: When i increase some integer value to height calculated when GraphicsUnit.Point, what will be the result? Integer added to the height calculated is point or not?

Comment: @Amal I don't know what you mean - you're adding an `int` to a `float`. They're just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graphics.PageUnit in order to set the return type of measurement. So it can be either Pixel or Point, it is your choice